# What are the other good santizers when StarSan is not available?

Tags: first-time-brewer, sanitizer

I'm a first timer from India and literally nothing for beer home brewing is available locally.
I'm having a hard time finding airlock, siphon tube , bottle capper etc. Please bear with me if its a stupid question. I've searched almost every other place

Comment: I think you can use bleach, but I would be very careful with it: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11907/sanitizing-with-bleach-without-rinsing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've brewed for years without starsan.

- Bleach, as mentioned in the above link, is good for fermenters and
  bottles. Extra contact time (a few hours if possible) doesn't hurt.
  Keep away from metals, especially copper. Rinse away with boiled
  water. High concentrations are still my favorite for dissolving a mold colony in a hurry.
- Boiling: good for small items for 15-30. Some plastics will discolor
  or distort, but heat always works. Bottle caps might not like being boiled too long.
- Baking: For years my bottle sanitation method was to put rinsed &
  dried bottles in the oven at ~250F for an hour or so. Never had a
  problem.
- Alcohol: if you can get cheap vodka or dentaured alcohol, 50-90% does a great job and quickly. May damage some plastics, especially rigid plastic.
- Peroxyacetic acid is becoming more popular for hospital & food sanitation, and may be available in your area. Fast & effective, but may damage metals.

Comment: Thanks @Pepi, i ll wait a little more for more answers before i mark this right. :)

Comment: A lot of wine makers also use potassium metabisulfite and/or sodium metabisulfite (i.e. Campden tablets) to sanitize equipment and corks.

Comment: @valverij - add this as an answer, perhaps with some numbers if you have them?

Comment: As a wine maker I always use Potassium Metabisulfate. When I started making beer I just used the same. Never a problem.